# javascript onunload event behavior

Tags: javascript, android, browser

We have a webpage (let's say webpage 1) having multiple divs, which displays based on user operations.

On browser back operation, the page webpage1 is being redirected to another page webpage2. For this we are getting page onunload event.

This page receives this onunload operation multiple times i.e. for all the divs which were loaded previously. That is, if on webpage1, div1, div2, div3, div4 being accessed by user previously. and if he presses back button when div4 was open on webpage1 then we observe div4 --> (back operation)--> div3 --> (back operation)-->div2 --> (back operation)-->div1--> (back operation)--> onunload event received for div1 --> onunload event received for div2-->onunload event received for div3 --> onunload event received for div4 --> redirection to webpage1.

Why its happening? Any clue please. This behavior is on Android mobile browser.

Comment: What is the desired effect you want to happen?

Comment: The desired effect should be similar as we observe on PC browser. That is, it should get and handle onunload event just one time (not for each past divs loaded). This will ensure display of alert just single time.

Comment: Without seeing any code I would suspect that the method used to create the div is adding (appending) an onunload handler to the already existing ones. As your history state changes (going back) each one is called. If your doing any history state manipulation, which it seems like you are, for ajax or something else like using push state then each back/forward would fire all the onunloads. Is this only happening on Android and nothing else?

Comment: This is happening on IPhone Safari browser as well. But on IE9 (PC browser) we are not observing this behavior. As you commented, we are doing history state manipulation on the very first div (div1) which is loaded on webpage2. This is done so that we disable back operation (and present refresh behavior) when webpage2 with div1 is visible to user. In our case webpage1 is the login page and webpage2  with div2 is the main page (after login). And we don't want user to go back with back button to login page (i.e. webpage1) from webpage2 with div1. So, history state manipulation is done.